# [Invalid Resource Record: 'FATAL problem: ARRDATAIllegalIPv4Address (Value is not a valid IPv4 address) encountered with 'Parked'']

Tags: amazon-route53

I am encountering this problem while importing Godaddy my domain's zone file records to the Route s3 console.

[Invalid Resource Record: 'FATAL problem: ARRDATAIllegalIPv4Address (Value is not a valid IPv4 address) encountered with 'Parked'']